# Output MySQL variable to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

How can i output the MySQL variable set by the "AS variable" function in PHP?

```
function ClassBalance()
{
    global $con_char;

    $data = $con_char->prepare('SELECT 
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 1) AS warrior,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 2) AS paladin,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 3) AS hunter,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 4) AS rogue,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 5) AS priest,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 7) AS shaman,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 8) AS mage,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 9) AS warlock,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 11) AS druid');
    $data->execute();

    while($result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo $row['warrior'];
        }
    }
}

ClassBalance();
```

I cannot get it to work in any way, it does neither output any errors so i dont know how to proceed with this.

Appreciates all the help i can get on this subject.

Comment: a join and a table matching the ids to names would be a better approach

Comment: You have 2 SELECT in the beginning. Also I do not think PDO supports multiple SELECTS. And you should turn on Error 'PDOException' to get info.

Answer (score -1):

[test this code][1]

```
function ClassBalance()
{
    global $con_char;

    $data = $con_char->prepare('SELECT 
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 1) AS warrior,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 2) AS paladin,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 3) AS hunter,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 4) AS rogue,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 5) AS priest,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 7) AS shaman,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 8) AS mage,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 9) AS warlock,
        (SELECT class FROM characters WHERE class = 11) AS druid');
    $data->execute();
    $store_array=array();
    while($result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
           array_push($store_array,$row);
        }
    }    
    return $store_array;
}

ClassBalance();
```

Comment: use this in function if validate is needed..[code]   while{......}
       # if (array_key_exists("warrior",$store_array))   
           return $store_array;
       else
           return '';#